# Microsoft office store acquisitions graph not updated

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office-store

In the microsoft office store partner center the "Analyze -> Acquisitions" graph for my outlook add-in is not updated for the last 10 days. It looks like it correlates with the day where I uploaded a new version of the add-in which was rejected by the seller dashboard team. But the old version is still available in the office store, so I would expect to see acquisitions for the add-in.

The add-in is named Plandisc, and I have been running e-mail marketing campaigns this week, so I would expect some acquisitions, and not zero as the graph shows.

Comment: There was an outage for a portion of November but this has been resolved. For any further issues, please contact support at the link below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metrics run on a standard SLA of 4 days behind the current date.

Any issues with individual metrics should be reported to [Support Team](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=272975) via the App Analytics and Commerece option